# Accidentally wiped out PATH definition in Bash shell

Tags: bash

I created a.bash_profile and defined

```
    export PATH=/user/local/bin
```

rather than

```
    export PATH=/user/local/bin:$PATH
```

Then, I ran

```
    source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now none of the command, e.g., ls works. Is there a way to back out this change? Thank you.

Comment: just edit and fix and run the source command again.

Answer (score 3):

If you have fixed your `.bash_profile` file, you just restart `bash` to get your `$PATH` back.  If that's not an option, or you can't fix the file externally, you can do `export PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"`, which should give you enough to get to `vi` or some other text editor so you can fix your `.bash_profile`, then you can restart `bash`.